# find number that is not 0 in a varchar sequence like 0000000001 or 00000123131

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, I have to manipulate char values in table. I have a table that has values like 000000011,000000123,0000012312.

I need to recreate a new id from this column but only to keep the number that is not a '0'

So far I´ve tried with `CHARINDEX`, and `SUBSTRING` and none of those worked

Thank you for you help

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: ANSI SQL: `trim(leading '0' from column)`

Comment: Only the left 0 or all the 0? you can change it to Int and all the left 0 will desapear.

Comment: `cast(the_column as integer)`

Answer (score 2):

you can use  trim leading

```
 TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM '000000011' )


 TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM your_column )
```

or cast

```
 SELECT (CAST your_column AS int)
```

Comment: Should be supported by any dbms claiming ANSI SQL compliance.

Comment: @jarlh  thanks   .. that's better  ..  anyway answer  updated  with various solutions

Comment: Yes, of the above, only TRIM LEADING and CAST versions are ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: The `REPLACE` isn't correct. It will turn `0000010000` into `1`